# study of the sequence (Un) defined by $U_{0}=a$ and $U_{n+1}=a+\frac{1-b^{-n}}{2}.U_{n} $ .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let a and b be real numbers such that a>0 and b>1. Consider the sequence (Un) defined by $U_{0}=a$ and $U_{n+1}=a+\frac{1-b^{-n}}{2}.U_{n} $ .

Show that (Un) is bounded, convergent and find its limit.
To prove that the sequence is bounded i intuitively used the fixed point theorem because at first glance i don't really know the appropriate way to study this sequence as it's neither arithmetic nor geometric or the both. Thus i found as the limit $l=\frac{2a}{1+b^{-n}}$, thereafter i obtained $2a>Un>a$. But at this moment that's just a conjecture. Then i proved it by induction.

This part of the question solved, the rest become easier (convergence and limit); but i don't really know if my proof is correct and i am looking for nice ways to prove this sequence is bounded.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to recognize $U_n$ and $U_{n+1}$ can be replaced with the limit, call it $L$, when $n$ is very large. This gives us, $$L=a+\frac{1-b^{-n}}{2} L$$

Now, solving this we get $L=\frac{2a}{1+b^{-n}}$. This limit is bounded above by $2a$.

Comment: Please upvote/select as answer if helpful.